# Why I am redirecting to "Google.com" when tried Google Login in React Native Expo App?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I am trying to add Google Login in my Expo React Native application and following official expo documentation from here [Auth with Google](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/google-authentication/).

When I login through Expo Play Store App it is working completely fine, but when I build apk by EAS services it is loading for some time and redirecting me to "www.google.com".

I am a beginner and not able to solve this for more than 20 hours now. Please help.

Here is my Login Screen Code and other files.

```
import { StyleSheet, View, LogBox, Pressable, Text } from "react-native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Fonts from "../utils/Fonts";
import Colors from "../utils/Colors";
import { db } from "../utils/firebase";
import GoogleIcon from "../icons/GoogleIcon";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import { LivornLogoIcon } from "../icons/HeaderIcons";
import { ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import FormComponent from "../components/FormComponent";
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";
import { useAndroidRipple } from "../hooks/useAndroidRipple";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import PrimaryButtonComponent from "../components/PrimaryButtonComponent";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
LogBox.ignoreLogs(["The useProxy option is deprecated and will be removed in a future release"]);

export default function LoginScreen({ setUserLoginInfo }) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const [inviteCode, setInviteCode] = useState();
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(true);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    // iosClientId: "",
    androidClientId: // My ID
    expoClientId: // My ID
    webClientId: // My ID
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    handleEffect();
  }, [response, token]);

  async function handleEffect() {
    const user = await getLocalUser();
    if (!user) {
      if (response?.type === "success") {
        setToken(response.authentication.accessToken);
        getUserInfo(response.authentication.accessToken);
      }
    } else {
      setUserLoginInfo(user);
    }
  }

  const getLocalUser = async () => {
    const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user");
    if (!data) return null;
    return JSON.parse(data);
  };

  const getUserInfo = async (token) => {
    if (!token) return;
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      });

      const user = await response.json();
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@user", JSON.stringify(user));
      setUserLoginInfo(user);
    } catch (error) {
      // Add your own error handler here
    }
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LivornLogoIcon scale={6} marginLeft={10} />
      {isAuthorized && (
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Pressable
            disabled={!request}
            style={styles.googleButton}
            onPress={() => promptAsync()}
            android_ripple={useAndroidRipple(170)}
          >
            <GoogleIcon scale={0.35} marginRight={12} />
            <Text style={Fonts.primaryText}>Continue with Google</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 100,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    backgroundColor: Colors.blackTheme.backgroundPrimary,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    width: "80%",
    marginTop: 20,
    overflow: "hidden",
    borderRadius: 100,
  },
  googleButton: {
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 100,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: Colors.blackTheme.buttonAndIconColor,
  },
  errorMessage: {
    color: "red",
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: -40,
  },
});
```

This is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Livorn",
    "slug": "Livorn",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/LivornAdaptiveIcon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/LivornSplashScreen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/LivornAdaptiveIcon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      },
      "package": "company.cubes.Livorn"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/LivornFavicon.png"
    },
    "scheme": "Livorn",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "b198162a-e569-4414-8d5f-86148568b764"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In app.json.

Make slug and scheme both to lowercase and equal. It would solve the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11317#issuecomment-1632501886
I also needed to update the AndroidManifest.xml file (or maybe another prebuild would wipe out the android/ folder and put the correct values in there).